# Java - Script let to model class with loop

Tags: java, jsp

I'm trying to remove some scriptlets from my jsp and almost have the same identical
code but my model class is somehow throwing an error.  The main difference is the JcrUtils.getChildNodes() command which essentially calls Node.getNodes() on a node and returns an Iterable instance. I've been racking my brain for hours on this and can't figure it out:

**JSP:**

```
final String HEADER = "header"
final Node headerNode = currentNode.hasNode(HEADER)

NodeIterator childLinks = headerNode.getNodes();

while ( childLinks.hasNext() ) {
  Node link = (Node) childLinks.next();
  headerNode = link.getProperty("headerTitle");
  //do something with more child node properties
}
```

**MODEL CLASS:**

```
final String HEADER = "header"
final Node headerNode = currentNode.hasNode(HEADER)

def headerNodeTitle = JcrUtils.getChildNodes(headerNode).find{ it.hasProperty("headerTitle") }
selectHeaderLabel = topicNode.getProperty("headerTitle").getString();
```

**ERROR**

```
No signature of method: static org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.JcrUtils.getChildNodes() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [true]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based in the error message, the `JcrUtils.getChildNodes(...)` expects a `String` type parameter. Review this piece of code and also the code `JcrUtils.getChildNodes(headerNode)` that you invoke passing an object of `Node` type.